# Get the message metadata from an Azure Function QueueTrigger using Java

Tags: java, azure-functions, azure-storage, micronaut

I am writing an Azure Function in Java using the Micronaut framework.

My function works perfectly fine if I use the `@QueueTrigger` to annotate a `String` to receive a message body.  However I would also like to process the metadata.

The documentation makes mention of Metadata (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=java#message-metadata) and "suggests" the `CloudQueueMessage` class, which doesn't seem to be available in the `com.microsoft.azure.funtions:azure-functions-java-library` I even tried including the `com.azure:azure-storage-queue` library on the off chance.
(As far as I can tell `azure-functions-java-library` hasn't moved over to the `com.azure` name space/GAV yet)

Is it possible to obtain the Storage Queue message metadata using Java and if so, what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was missing something, that you can "bind" to properties of the metadata that are held in `CloudQueueMessage` class.

So for my use case all I need to do is add the following to the function method:

```java
@BindingName("Id") final String id,
```

The following links are all to Microsoft documentation, the last one of which is hosted on github.
[Trigger Metadata definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#trigger-metadata)
[QueueStorage Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=java#example)
[Example that actually accesses the metadata](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-library#metadata)